# How to avoid too much nesting in Sequelize queries with nested include queries?

Tags: mysql, nested, sequelize.js, include, left-join

```
{
"id": 1,
"uuid": "20-zdswny16so",
"productName": "Air Jordan 1",
"description": "Legendary and iconic.",
"retailPrice": "22000",
"wholesalePrice": 21000,
"hex": "#000000",
"gender.id": 3,
"gender.name": "women",
-> "product.category.id": 1,      <<<<<<<<
-> "product.category.name": "sneakers",   <<<<<<<<
"color.id": 2,
"color.name": "black"
}
```

Before providing an answer:
I know the term nesting not quite right here.
I'm using "raw" to avoid object nesting in the first place

Query:

```
const items = await models.Item.findAll(  
        {
            raw:true,
            
            attributes: [
                "id",
                "uuid",
                'product.productName',
                "product.description",
                "retailPrice",
                "wholesalePrice",
                "color.hex"
            ],
 
            include: [{
                model:models.Gender,
                attributes:['id','name'],
              
             
            },  
            {
                model: models.Product,
                attributes:[],
                include: [{
                    model:models.Category,
                    attributes:['id','name'],
                }]
            },{
                model: models.Color,
                attributes:['id','name'],
            }],
             
        });
```

As  you can see there are multilevel includes:

For the Gender,Product,Color Model its ok (first level)
**but Category Model and so on would be bad!**

**The idea is product.category.id  to become ----> category.id**

Moving column names from Category to Product ATTRIBUTES don't work like for Product to TOP QUERY (sry if badly explained).

Comment: only if you indicate aliases for each column from included models listed in the main `attributes` prop